# mongodb "all" conditional operator implemented in mysql database

Tags: mysql, mongodb, in-operator

How can I translate "all" conditional operator present in mongodb in mysql database?
So for example, I have a list of tags in a table "tags":

```
table tags:
id   user_id    name
 1   5          apple  
 2   5          banana
 3   5          pear
 4   7          strawberry
 5   7          kiwi
```

I want query this table for retrieve user_id that has apple **AND** banana tags. So, IN operator isn't correct because it retrieve user_id that has apple OR banana. If tags are limited, for example apple and banana I can query with AND operator, but I could query 20 tags so I don't want make 20 and operator -> name = "banada" and name = "pear" and name = "apple" and....

In mongodb search all terms in array it use "all" conditional operator.
How can I do same thing in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic answer is:

```
SELECT user_id FROM tags
WHERE name in ('apple','banana', ...18 other names...)
GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*)=20
```